How can I split an Edge into two independent edges from the center?
My goal is to split an edge into two, with one edge on either side (similar to the purple direction/red line edge example), instead of doing it simply twice on each side. Is there a way to do this, as it is similar to a bevel?


If you do that you're going to end up with four ngons instead of quads on the front and rear sides of the cube. Is there any reason why you can't bevel that loop? You'll have edges all round the object but that wouldn't normally cause any problems.

Hi Pyratae I have revised my answer to hopefully suit your needs

I’ve created an Operator that splits a selected edge into two separate edges. To use it, copy the script provided at the end of this post and paste it into the Text Editor. Click Run Script to create and register the operator. After registering, select an edge in Edit Mode, press F3, search for "My Split Edge" and execute the operator to split the edge.
Optionally, you can adjust the distance between the new edges by selecting the face and pressing S<axis> (e.g., SX). If your object isn’t aligned to the grid, as in my case, be sure to set the Transformation Orientation to Normal for accurate adjustments.

You can also create a custom keymap for the operator by going to Edit > Preferences > Keymap > 3D View > 3D View (Global) and adding the operator name. For example, I’ve configured the shortcut as CtrlJ.

Now I can simply select an edge and use this shortcut to split the edge:

Copy the script and paste it into the Text Editor. Click Run Script to create and register the operator.
import bpy
import bmesh

class MESH_OT_split_edge(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "mesh.my_split_edge"
    bl_label = "My Split Edge"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        return obj is not None and obj.mode == 'EDIT'

    def execute(self, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
        selected_edges = [e for e in bm.edges if e.select]

        if len(selected_edges) != 1:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "Select exactly one edge")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        original_edge = selected_edges[0]
        v1, v2 = original_edge.verts
        adjacent_faces = original_edge.link_faces

        if len(adjacent_faces) != 2:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "The selected edge does not have exactly two adjacent faces")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        perpendicular_edges = set()

        # Directly select the first edge connected to each vertex in the adjacent faces
        for face in adjacent_faces:
            for edge in face.edges:
                if edge != original_edge:
                    if v1 in edge.verts or v2 in edge.verts:
                        perpendicular_edges.add(edge)
                        if len(perpendicular_edges) >= 4:
                            break

        if len(perpendicular_edges) != 4:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "Unexpected number of perpendicular edges found: {}".format(len(perpendicular_edges)))
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        for edge in perpendicular_edges:
            edge.select_set(True)

        bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=1)
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        original_edge.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.mesh.dissolve_edges()
        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)
        
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MESH_OT_split_edge)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MESH_OT_split_edge)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Nice, now we're only missing a geonodes solution.

@MarkusvonBroady I revised the script :D

Nice, it's basically a bevel but one that doesn't fix/mess neighboring topology.

@MarkusvonBroady true! could actually do this as a modal operator with increasing subdivisions functionality like the bevel

Select the vertical edges, right-click, "Subdivide", press F9 to bring the operator settings, change the number of cuts to 2:

If you want to have the additional loopcut as on your screenshot, you can do it first, then subdivide the 2 pairs of vertical edges, and then dissolve (X) the middle edge:

